# Anyone knows of an example of a good bar graph generated using Raphael?

Tags: javascript, raphael

Does anyone know any example of a Raphael bar graph? I checked gRaphael but the bar graph that it generates is not what I want. I want a bar graph that looks like the graph here - http://www.rgraph.net/canvas/bar.html#example . I don't want to use rgraph as it's not free for commercial applications.

**EDIT:** Now, RGraph is indeed entirely free - licensed using the MIT Open Source license

Answer (score 2):

If Raphael is not a hard requirement, you could take a look at [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic). They have a nifty javascript charting library.

Comment: Thanks, I did check HighCharts before. The application I am working on is not commercial; but there are plans for making it freely downloadable. I think it can be an issue if people start using it for commercial uses and we use something like HighCharts or rgraph, as they are not free for commercial usage. They are great products nevertheless. I just hope their kind of features will be available in gRaphael (or other free JS chart libraries).

Comment: What kind of licences are compatible with your application ?

Comment: If Mit licence works for you, you could check out jqplot. http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Raphael's graphing sub-library, [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)?

There are bar chart examples on the gRaphael home page. Just navigate to them and view their source.

Hope that helps.